# Create dynamic prototype like jquery function chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create a dynamic prototype like jQuery and able to function chain, but I got error without use new and inside of function, return `this` object correct?

```js
    (function() {
      var peopleDynamicProto = function(name, age, state) {

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.state = state;

        if (typeof this.printPerson !== 'function') {
          peopleDynamicProto.prototype.printPerson = function() {
            console.log(this.name + ',' + this.age + ',' + this.state);
            return this;
          };
        }

        if (!this.hasOwnProperty('gender')) {
          peopleDynamicProto.prototype.gender = 'male';
          return this;
        }
      }

      window.peopleDynamicProto = peopleDynamicProto;
      return peopleDynamicProto;

    })();

     //var person1 = new peopleDynamicProto('john', 23,'CA');
     //person1.printPerson();

    peopleDynamicProto('john', 23, 'CA').printPerson(); //got error
```

Anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use "new" if you want to create a new object based off a prototype.
I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, and why you are trying to create the prototype dynamically. I'm not going to say 100% sure, but I don't think jQuery does that (plus it looks like a very bad practice).
If you're trying to do something like jQuery, where your class is chainable and can be chained as `(new peopleDynamicProto(...)).print()` or `peopleDynamicProto(...).print()`, then you can do something like this:

```
function peopleDynamicProto(name) {
  if (this instanceof peopleDynamicProto) {
    /* initialize attributes here */
    this.name = name;
  } else {
    return new peopleDynamicProto(name);
  }
}

peopleDynamicProto.prototype.printPerson = function() {
   console.log( this.name );
   return this;
}
```

Now you should be able call it in both ways:

```
peopleDynamicProto('john').printPerson();
(new peopleDynamicProto('john')).printPerson();
```

If you don't care about supporting both ways, then you can just return an object, e.g.:

```
function peopleDynamicProto(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    printPerson = function() {
      console.log( this.name );
      return this;
    }
  };
}

peopleDynamicProto('John').printPerson();
```

(There are other ways of doing that)

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason why you are getting such an error is because what you are returning here is a function not an object but you are trying to access a property of an object.

For eg, 
If you write as:

**

```
var myFun = function(){
 this.message = "TEST";
}
```

**

you cannot access myFUN.message because here **myFun is a function not an object of this function constructor**.

To access its property, you need to do something like 
**(new myFun()).message**;

Similarly in you case what you return is **"peopleDynamicProto" which is a function only, not an object of this function constructor**.

**To access method printPerson (which is a member), you need to create an instance of peopleDynamicProto and access its member**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed the `new` operator- [`see this for reference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

See demo below:

```js
(function() {
  var peopleDynamicProto = function(name, age, state) {

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.state = state;

    if (typeof this.printPerson !== 'function') {
      peopleDynamicProto.prototype.printPerson = function() {
        console.log(this.name + ',' + this.age + ',' + this.state);
        return this;
      };
    }

    if (!this.hasOwnProperty('gender')) {
      peopleDynamicProto.prototype.gender = 'male';
      return this;
    }
  }

  window.peopleDynamicProto = peopleDynamicProto;
  return peopleDynamicProto;

})();

var person1 = new peopleDynamicProto('john', 23,'CA');
person1.printPerson();

new peopleDynamicProto('john', 23, 'CA').printPerson(); //got error
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant create prototype inside contructor. see this explanation
[defining-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115594/defining-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor)

use this keyword instead of prototype:

```
(function(){
    var peopleDynamicProto = function(name, age, state){

    this.name   = name;
    this.age    = age;
    this.state  = state;

    this.printPerson = function(){
            console.log( this.name + ',' + this.age + ',' + this.state );
            return this;

    }
    if( !this.hasOwnProperty('gender') ){
        peopleDynamicProto.prototype.gender = 'male';
        return this;
    } 
}
window.peopleDynamicProto = peopleDynamicProto;
return peopleDynamicProto;
})();

peopleDynamicProto('john', 23,'CA').printPerson();
```

or use prototype outside constructor(this is better since function object not recreated each time object created)

```
(function(){
 var peopleDynamicProto = function(name, age, state){

    this.name   = name;
    this.age    = age;
    this.state  = state;

    if( !this.hasOwnProperty('gender') ){
        peopleDynamicProto.prototype.gender = 'male';
        return this;
    } 
}
if( typeof this.printPerson !== 'function' ){
        peopleDynamicProto.prototype.printPerson = function(){
            console.log( this.name + ',' + this.age + ',' + this.state );
            return this;
        };
    }
 window.peopleDynamicProto = peopleDynamicProto;
return peopleDynamicProto;
})();
```

Comment: why u repeat this.printPerson & peopleDynamicProto.prototype.printPerson

Comment: typo. btw thankyou...  i can comment everywhere now, because of you :)